# XML Dom processing

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to modify xml file using dom ,but when I make node.getNodeValue(); it returns null !I don't know why? my xml file contains the following tags:
`[person] which contains child [name] which contains childs [firstname ,middleInitial ,lastName]  childs`

I want to update First name , middleInitial and last name using dom
this is my java dom processing file:

```
    NodeList refPeopleList = doc.getElementsByTagName("person");
```

`for (int i = 0; i < refPeopleList.getLength(); i++) {

            NodeList personList = refPeopleList.item(i).getChildNodes();
            for (int personDetalisCnt = 0; personDetalisCnt < refPeopleList.getLength(); personDetalisCnt++) {
                {
                    currentNode = personList.item(personDetalisCnt);
                    String nodeName = currentNode.getNodeName();
                    System.out.println("node name is " + nodeName);
                    if (nodeName.equals("name")) {
                        System.out.println("indise name");
                         NodeList nameList = currentNode.getChildNodes();
                         for(int cnt=0;cnt<nameList.getLength();cnt++)
                         {
                             currentNode=nameList.item(cnt);
                             if(currentNode.getNodeName().equals("firstName"))
                             {
                                  System.out.println("MODIFID NAME :"+currentNode.getNodeValue()); //prints null
                                  System.out.println("indide fname"+" node name is "+currentNode.getNodeName()); //prints firstName
                                  String nodeValue="salma";
                                 currentNode.setNodeValue(nodeValue);
                                  System.out.println("MODIFID NAME :"+currentNode.getNodeValue());//prints null


                             }
                         }
                    }
                }`

Comment: You may write a simple helper class to accomplish your task around DOM. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346867/851432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `getNodeValue()` / `setNodeValue()` on the `<firstName>` element node, try getting the firstName element's text node child, and call  `getNodeValue()` / `setNodeValue()` on it.

Try

```
if(currentNode.getNodeName().equals("firstName"))
{
   Node textNode = currentNode.getFirstChild();
   System.out.println("Initial value:" + textNode.getNodeValue());
   String nodeValue="salma";
   textNode.setNodeValue(nodeValue);
   System.out.println("Modified value:" + textNode.getNodeValue());
}
```

From the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-BBACDC08),

> The attributes nodeName, nodeValue and
>   attributes are included as a mechanism
>   to get at node information without
>   casting down to the specific derived
>   interface. In cases where there is no
>   obvious mapping of these attributes
>   for a specific nodeType (e.g.,
>   nodeValue for an **Element** or attributes
>   for a Comment), this returns **null**.

Similarly in the Java docs for the [Node interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), the table near the top shows that the nodeValue of an element is null.

This is why using getNodeValue on an element will always return null, and why you need to use [getFirstChild](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getFirstChild%28%29)() first in order to get the text node (assuming there are no other child nodes). If there is a mixture of element and text child nodes, you can use [getNodeType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeType%28%29)() to check which child is which (text is type 3).

Comment: firstName element is simple data type , it doesn't have childs , how can i get element child?

Comment: firstName element doesn't have child *elements*, but it does have a child *text node*. The text inside the firstName element is not on element itself, but is the value of the element's text node child.

Comment: @Alaa, I edited my answer to give more details about child text nodes.

Comment: i make like this , but still not working , i don't know where i am making the mistake!  String nodeValue="alaa"; currentNode.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(nodeValue); 
by the way , ur answer hasn't been changed !!

Comment: @Alaa, if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4018398/revisions you can see when my answer changed.

Comment: @Alaa, when you do `currentNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue()` what is the result?

Comment: :) it works , many thanx mr @LarsH , thanx for being sooooo patient.

Answer (score 0):

Is it `firstName` or `firstname` (watch the case).

Comment: it's firstName , it's just writing mistake